# how to change sheet name in report-builder 2.0

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a report using report-builder 2.0 and i want to change the name of sheet while exporting data from ssrs to excel

**Is there any way to change the name of default sheet name to custom sheet name ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can name the PageBreak in the properties of whatever it is configured for. For example, I have a report that has 7 different tables with the intent of it being exported to Excel with each table being its own separately named sheet. With the exception of the first table, every table has a page break configured for before the tablix. When I select the tablix, and go to properties, I can then name the PageName to whatever I would like the sheet to be named.

[image: Tablix Page Break]

If I were to have the page break occur based on row groups in the tablix, I would select the Row Groups from the tablix, go to properties, and the page break, and then modify the PageName.
[image: Group Page Break]

Comment: pagename is available in version 3
i am using version 2.0 and i have mentioned it in my question that i am using version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I also not found in report builder 2.0  version, I changed pageName by editing report file on 3.0 version cause there available pageName proporty. *There is no any conflicts to editing with newer version.*

Comment: The OP obviously knows how to accomplish this with version 3.0. There is also an answer describing it. You did not find the functionality in version 2.0 - so did the OP. The best answer to this would be: Feature XY was added in version 3.0 see changelog <link>. Not sure if there are people still using version 2.0, but adding answers after 4 years with no new information should be avoided.